# Issues getting ApplicationContext within a Java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

So I am trying to get applicationContext within a simple utility class but all my attempts so far yielded in a `null` object. How do I get hold of applicationContext in `Sample.java`.

**First approach:**

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware
{

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext()
    {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext( ApplicationContext ac ) throws BeansException
    {
        context = ac;
    }
}
```

Defined this bean in applicationContext as:

```
 <bean id="applicationContextProvder" class="com.premier.web.utils.ApplicationContextProvider"/>
```

Used it within my Java class as:

```
ApplicationContextProvider ctx = new ApplicationContextProvider();
ctx.getApplicationContext(); //Results in a null
```

**Second approach:**
Directly `AutoWired` the applicationContext within my class.

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;
```

Comment: I don't believe the first approach failing can be explained by the duplicate answer...

Comment: @Adam `new ApplicationContextProvider();` is not a managed bean. From the duplicate _The field annotated `@Autowired` is null because Spring doesn't know about the copy of MileageFeeCalculator that you created with `new` and didn't know to autowire it._ Replace `@Autowired` with `ApplicationContextAware`.

Comment: Agreed, however he's using a static reference inside the bean.. in the first approach...

Comment: I don't see how that changes anything. Whether the field is `static` or not, it won't be set because `setApplicationContext` isn't called because the `ApplicationContextProvider` instance is not a bean.

Comment: He also creates it in an application context, " <bean id="applicationContextProvder" class="com.premier.web.utils.ApplicationContextProvider"/>
" earlier... which I would expect to have the side effect of setting the static field....

Comment: Obviously all this is a massive misuse of spring, but I would have been interested in investigating how things behaved in this corner case...

Comment: @adam It would, indirectly, if it was a bean. Spring finds all `ApplicationContextAware` beans and invokes their `setApplicationContext` method, which would have set the `static` field. But this is not a Spring bean.

Comment: folks, this is just some trial thing on my end. I did define the 'ApplicationContextProvider' as a bean. That isn't enough?

Comment: No, you have to use the bean defined in the context. Here, you are instantiating the class yourself. Read the duplicate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have tested the approach given in "First approach" above. This actually works, despite your claims otherwise. I suspect the issue is the ordering of the bean being initialised and the call to ctx.getApplicationContext();

Comment: @Adam It definitely doesn't work. You must have use an `ApplicationContext`. There is no `ApplicationContext` in the question as aksed.

Comment: I agree with Sotirius. This is the idea behind container. Please see example usage here: http://www.concretepage.com/spring/example_applicationcontextaware_spring